# array.splice ignores one of the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to delete all the **zeros** in the array **nums** but for some reason the **splice()** method ignores one of the zeros. Can you tell me what the reason is?

```
var deleteZeroes = function(nums) {
  
    for(var i=0 ; i<nums.length ; i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]===0)
                {
                  nums.splice(i,1)
               
                }
        }
       
      return nums
};

deleteZeroes([0,0,4,0,3])
```

Comment: You keep mutating the array you're iterating on...

Comment: `nums.length` will change with each iteration.

Comment: The first item is zero. You remove it. Everything moves one place down. The first item is now zero. However, you increase `i` and check index `1` now.

Comment: `[0,0,4,0,3].filter( el => el)` will filter all zeros `// --> [4,3]`

Comment: @haim770 how can I solve it.

Comment: An alternate way to make it work, is to iterate from the end in reverse, like  `(var i=nums.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) { //same code you have...} `

Comment: @Leonardo I am not trying to create a new array.  I want the removal to be in place.

Comment: thanks, @RPDP. can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Zaid, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not trying to create a new array and want to remove in the same array, an alternate way to make it work, is to iterate from the end in reverse, like

```
(var i=nums.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) { 
   //same code you have...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The task can be performed using the `filter()` method

**Example: 1**

```js
var deleteZeroes = function(nums) {
    var n = nums.filter(x => x !== 0);
    return n
};

console.log(deleteZeroes([0,0,4,0,3]));
```

**Example: 2** *(Short syntax)*

```js
var deleteZeroes = (nums) => (nums.filter(x => x));

console.log(deleteZeroes([0,0,4,0,3]));
```